# Print type of object referenced by base-class pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, rtti

If I have class A, and class B which subclasses A, should `typeid(x)` give the type of A or the type of B, if x is given by:

`A *x = new B();`

In my tests I get the type of A - which is not very useful - but I'm not sure if that's due to how C++ works, or if this is due to compiler settings?

Comment: Oh, that was easy! I thought my sample code was a typo but actually that _was_ the problem. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Will work only if you have at least one `virtual` function in the base class.

Comment: I'm 110% sure that you aren't getting "the type of A", at least not if you're on a conforming compiler.

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah you're right, that _was_ a typo. Or rather, that confusion was the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

// Remember to add a virtual member function in A
// to enable RTTI.
struct A { virtual ~A() {} };

struct B : A { virtual ~B() {}};

int main()
{
   A* ap = new B();
   std::cout << typeid(ap).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(*ap).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output, with g++ 4.8.2:

```
P1A
1B
```